# how can I use string to the out

Tags: r

I have a data like this

```
     df<- structure(list(Mydata = c("AAA_F1", "AAA_F2", "AAA_F3"), T = c("T1", 
"T2", "T3"), X100 = c(500, 0, 12257.1), X10M = c(0L, 1100L, 0L
), F3100 = c(200L, 0L, 400L), X220M = c(0L, 0L, 0L), X400M = c(100, 
0, 2490.1), X600 = c(0L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

I am trying to get the median and sd as two different data frames, I am doing the following but I dont get what I want so, the first line should give me the median of each 3 values from each column
and the second must give the standard deviation of each three values of each column. I thought I must group them with the naming. I tried the following but didn't work

```
df_median <- as.data.frame(df %>% group_by(Mydata) %>% summarise_all(funs(median)))
df_sd <- as.data.frame(df %>% group_by(Mydata) %>% summarise_all(funs(sd)))
```

I can get the output with

```
lapply(dat[-c(1,2)], sd)
```

but it does not give me the same structure.

The output should look like this for instance for median

```
Mydata T    X100      X10M    F3100   X220M    X400M  X600
AAA    T    7611.5.     0     400      0       500    0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the code below

```
df[1:2] <- lapply(df[1:2], function(x) gsub("_.*|(?<=T)\\d+", "", x, perl = TRUE))
df_median <- aggregate(. ~ Mydata + T, df, median)
df_sd <- aggregate(. ~ Mydata + T, df, sd)
```

such that

```
> df_median
  Mydata T X100 X10M F3100 X220M X400M X600
1    AAA T  500    0   200     0   100    0
> df_sd 
  Mydata T     X100     X10M F3100 X220M    X400M X600
1    AAA T 6936.809 635.0853   200     0 1409.679    0
```

Comment: I am interested in your first line of code, is there a way to make it to remove replicate so that I can simply bind to the data instead of aggregate because I get error when I use different format of data. it would be great to get `Mydata T AAA T` so that I cbind

Comment: @nik What's the general patterns for strings in `Mydata` and `T` columns?